# rasterVis plot3D in R: obtain consistent x-y axes with extent() / projection() shown in RasterLayer object

Tags: r

**I have a `RasterLayer` object z:**

```
class       : RasterLayer 

dimensions  : 100, 100, 10000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)

resolution  : 0.06534037, 0.03165736  (x, y)

extent      : -96.63908, -90.10505, 40.36051, 43.52624  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

data source : in memory

names       : layer 

values      : 0.001829022, 2.227507  (min, max)
```

The latitude and longitude coordinates shown with `extent(z)` represents the state of Iowa in the U.S.  The function **plot(z)** produces a plot with the x-y axes consistent with the coordinates represented with `extent(z)`, as well as the coordinate reference with `projection(z)` shown above.

However, the function **`plot3D(z)`** produces a plot with the x-y axes inconsistent with the coordinates represented with `extent(z)`, and the coordinate reference with `projection(z)` shown above.  The function `plot3D(z)` is apparently using a different coordinate reference system than what is shown above in my `RasterLayer` object z.

**Question:** I would like the axes on the 3D plot (using the function **plot3D**) to continue using the latitude and longitude shown with extent(z), which is also consistent with the reference coordinate system projection(z) shown above.

**A reproducible example for illustration:**

```
library(maps)

library(maptools)

library(akima)

library(raster)

library(rasterVis)

library(rgl)

x <- runif(10, -95, -92)

y <- runif(10, 41, 43)

intensity <- runif(10, 0, 2)

iowa <- map("state", "iowa", fill = TRUE, col = "transparent", plot = TRUE)

iowa.spat <- map2SpatialPolygons(iowa, IDs = c("iowa"))

interp <- interp.new(x, y, intensity,

                     xo = seq(min(iowa$x, na.rm = TRUE),

                              max(iowa$x, na.rm = TRUE), length = 100),

                     yo = seq(min(iowa$y, na.rm = TRUE),

                              max(iowa$y, na.rm = TRUE), length = 100),

                     extrap = TRUE)

interp.raster <- raster(interp)

z <- mask(interp.raster, iowa.spat)

z

plot(z)

rgl::open3d()

plot3D(z)

decorate3d()
```

Comment: Screenshot?  Reproducible example? It is not just an aspect ratio thing is it?

Comment: In response to your timely comment, I modified my question to include a reproducible example.  Look forward to hearing your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

It's because plot3D is just scaling the z values to deal with the radically different scales in plotting "heights" against longitude/latitude values.

It's better to scale the aspect ratio since you don't then have to fake anything.

Try this, see how everything is perfect with `adjust = FALSE` - it's just that degrees and metres don't belong in the same space.

```
plot3D(z, adjust = FALSE)
decorate3d()
```

Set the aspect ratio (rather than munge the data):

```
aspect3d(1, 1, 1e-1)
```

fwiw, rgl has a lot more power than some of these high level plot wrappers expose - if you are really keen, try installing `quadmesh`.

```
## note, this did use "gris", which was never generally available
library(quadmesh) ## install.packages("quadmesh")
## create quad mesh
qm <- quadmesh(z, z)
scl <- function(x) (x - min(x, na.rm = TRUE))/diff(range(x, na.rm = TRUE))
shade3d(qm, col = terrain.colors(64)[scl(qm$vb[3,]) * 64 + 1][qm$ib])
aspect3d(1, 1, 1e-1)
```

Better still, because we have a quad mesh rather than an inflexible affine raster, we can reproject the x/y vertices and repeat without any aspect ratio ad hockery:

```
library(rgdal)
## work transpose
qm$vb[1:2, ] <- t(project(t(qm$vb[1:2, ]), "+proj=laea +ellps=WGS84 +lon_0=-93 +lat_0=42"))
open3d()
shade3d(qm, col = terrain.colors(64)[scl(qm$vb[3,]) * 64 + 1][qm$ib])
```

This is not a terribly exciting data set, but might be worth trying with your real data.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, and in particular for the helpful context.  That's so important for my edification.  I was so sure that the issue pertained to extent() and projection() that I didn't allow myself to step back to see the forest from the trees.  In the end, I decided to move forward with your gris package, implementing the code that you had graciously provided on my data set.  I am very happy with the results.  Admittedly, I do like the name of the R package too.  A thousand thanks.

Comment: Just a note, I updated the answer to use CRAN's 'quadmesh' rather than the old 'gris' that was only on Github.